# Doesn't run Cypress & linux cron

Tags: linux, cron, cypress

I hope for your help. I installed Cypress in Linux and test successfully runs manually on the command `cypress run --record --key *******`

However, when I write the command to Cron, the test doesn't run. There are no errors in the console. Cron is working. Other commands, such as date and time output, work fine.

I did this:

1. Created a **bash-script.sh** with the following content

```html
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/project-name/cypress
/home/ubuntu/project-name/cypress/node_modules/.bin/cypress run --record --key *****************
```

2. Put the bash-script file into the folder /home/ubuntu/. This is now the path to the script /home/ubuntu/**bash-script.sh**
3. Via the command 'crontab -l ' scheduled the following command `*/5 * * * * /home/ubuntu/bash-script.sh >> /home/ubuntu/bash-script-log.log`

But the scheduled command is not executed. The logs are empty. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write the PATH variable at the beginning of the bash script. Just execute echo $PATH; in your terminal/bash and copy the result to make PATH variable as follows.

Let's first make sure that cypress is working in bash and then We will trigger this in crontab.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

## Set your cypress folder
yourfullpathtocypressfolder=/home/ubuntu/project-name/cypress;

## Check that we can echo cypress version
$yourfullpathtocypressfolder/node_modules/.bin/cypress -v >> Iamalive.log
```

After setting variable **yourfullpathtocypressfolder** Save your script as myscript.sh. try run this script as `bash myscript.sh` in your terminal.

As for the complete code to record your project using crontab as follows.
**Make sure that you are updated your projectID in cypress.json!**

You can also check this gist https://gist.github.com/senniksoft/0e062165fb9121be8d8a0fca4038fbc1

```
#!/bin/bash
        PATH=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
        
## Set your cypress folder
yourfullpathtocypressfolder=/home/ubuntu/project-name/cypress;
    
## Set your project key
yourprojectkey=xxxxxxxx-c69f-4c44-81c9-xxxxxxxxxxxxx;
    
cd $yourfullpathtocypressfolder;
        
## Example Code to record
./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --record --key $yourprojectkey --spec "cypress/integration/examples/actions.spec.js" >> RecordLog.log
```

After that give proper permissions so that crontab can execute the script.

`chmod +x /home/ubuntu/myscript.sh;`

Add this script to crontab as follows

```
*/5 * * * * bash /home/ubuntu/myscript.sh
```

Example output in the log after running this script.

```
====================================================================================================

  (Run Starting)

  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Cypress:    5.1.0                                                                              │
  │ Browser:    Electron 83 (headless)                                                             │
  │ Specs:      1 found (examples/actions.spec.js)                                                 │
  │ Searched:   cypress/integration/examples/actions.spec.js                                       │
  │ Params:     Tag: false, Group: false, Parallel: false                                          │
  │ Run URL:    https://dashboard.cypress.io/projects/2bn65e/runs/2                                │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                    
  Running:  examples/actions.spec.js                                                        (1 of 1)
  Estimated: 22 seconds


  Actions
    ✓ .type() - type into a DOM element (7441ms)
    ✓ .focus() - focus on a DOM element (469ms)
    ✓ .blur() - blur off a DOM element (741ms)
    ✓ .clear() - clears an input or textarea element (790ms)
    ✓ .submit() - submit a form (670ms)
    ✓ .click() - click on a DOM element (2705ms)
    ✓ .dblclick() - double click on a DOM element (476ms)
    ✓ .rightclick() - right click on a DOM element (360ms)
    ✓ .check() - check a checkbox or radio element (1114ms)
    ✓ .uncheck() - uncheck a checkbox element (1160ms)
    ✓ .select() - select an option in a <select> element (1068ms)
    ✓ .scrollIntoView() - scroll an element into view (798ms)
    ✓ .trigger() - trigger an event on a DOM element (383ms)
    ✓ cy.scrollTo() - scroll the window or element to a position (2321ms)


  14 passing (24s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My file now looks like: `#!/bin/bash
#echo PATH;
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin;
cypress run --record --key **************` but nothing has changed.

Comment: Your welcome. Can you try to run echo $PATH in your terminal and paste the result here ?

Comment: Yeah, sure. `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try to do as you said and write about the results. Thanks.

Comment: I succeeded thanks to your instructions. Thank you very much and good luck!

Comment: Your welcome Dear Jack. I am happy to solve the problem. Please accept the answer so that it helps others also.